# Installing Ruby 1.9 on OS X Leopard using /usr/local - RVM issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, bash, rvm

I have to run a Rails (3.0.6) app locally that requires Ruby 1.9.2 (plus Mongo). I'd like to install Ruby 1.9.2 alongside my existing 1.8.7 and be able to swap between them as necessary. I prefer installing to usr/local over Macports etc. Any recommendations? I've tried installing RVM but this has proved such a pain on OS X I'd rather avoid that too.

Is there another way of running multiple Ruby versions (maybe [with a prefix like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179959/best-practice-for-installing-multiple-versions-of-ruby-apart-from-rvm))? I only need to switch to 1.9 for this project. Or has anyone a good solution to the known OS X/RVM [install](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/bc658ca82c40a533) [issues](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/54aaa8bd1cf1ad26/7504e6e6d94e9546)? Specifically, on Tiger/10.4 bash doesn't support errtrace.

Update: solved with a new RVM install script: see [RVM on OS X 10.4 - possible?](http://bit.ly/qql9fx).

Comment: I'm not sure why installing RVM would be a pain. I've done it many times. The most important thing is to completely read the directions for installation, and to NOT use root for a single-user installation. Once it's installed type `rvm notes` and do what it says.

Comment: I'm aware of those things, but there are issues on OS X: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/bc658ca82c40a533

Answer (score 2):

RVM really is the easiest solution, and I would highly recommend you try and work that issue out first.

The only bit of advice is to make sure you configure your PATH variable to include /usr/local/bin *before* everything else. In your .profile or .login (depending on your shell), you should have it towards the bottom, in case there is any other lines configuring PATH as well, and then for the Bourne shell family:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

or for the C shell family:

`set path = (/usr/local/bin $PATH)`

Running ./configure alone should make it install into `/usr/local`, but you can explicitly state so with 
`./configure --prefix=/usr/local`

Comment: Already done that, but there are issues with the RVM install: http://bit.ly/mWkDBj

Comment: is Ruby really so broken that hard-wiring major and minor version numbers into applications really "the easiest solution" ?  Easier than 'git clone ; ./configure ; make' ?

Comment: Well, I might try that when I get back from a short holiday... yes, there is some breakage in the OS X system Ruby.

Comment: @Dmitri, "is Ruby really so broken that hard-wiring major and minor version numbers into applications really "the easiest solution" ?" Ruby isn't. Other people's code is.

Answer (score 1):

Install Ruby from source and it will default to /usr/local/bin. Adjust your path, the `#!` line, or your `/usr/local/bin/ruby source.rb` as necessary to switch between Apple's installation of Ruby, and the one you add.

You can force a new base directory using `./configure --prefix=/...` where '...' is whatever path you want. Again, once the files are installed, you can adjust the executing Ruby with one of the above methods.

Do not attempt to remove Apple's installed Ruby. It's there for their use, not for our convenience, and Apple uses it to provide some functionality. Messing with it or removing it could break things, and you probably wouldn't notice for a while.

RE: RVM, It really is the preferred way to install a user Ruby. I have it on two Macs, and a handful of different Linux boxes and the only time I had trouble was with a secured machine behind firewalls, but I can't blame RVM for those problems when it couldn't see the internet at all. And, yes, I got it working nicely, I just had to insert the manually downloaded Ruby archives into the `~/.rvm/archives` directory.

If you are having problems and want to use it, it might help to temporarily strip your startup scripts, or create a temporary user, and see what happens. Additionally, the author has been very responsive and helpful the few times I've asked him questions. Contact him at:

```
If you still cannot find what an answer to your question, find me 'wayneeseguin' in #rvm on irc.freenode.net:

    http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really clear - I'll try it next week when back from holidays - appreciate the IRC offer :-)

Comment: Still trying RVM install: got path in .bash_login (bottom of other stuff) all prerequisites exist. Running the command in the install instructions gave two empty dirs inside ~/.rvm, but 2 errors: line 6: set: errtrace: invalid option name, and line 166: conditional binary operator expected. Downloading and running the rvm.sh script itself does the same. I found that 10.4's bash doesn't support errtrace, commented out those lines, got the repo, but install threw similar errors in ./scripts/install (line 6: set: errtrace: invalid option name) yet 'install' is an empty file?

Comment: @dave-everitt you could try installing a new version of bash into /usr/local . Grab the build package from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/

Comment: @Kelvin - installed bash 4.2, but on `/usr/local/bin/bash --version` am getting: [...] /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture [...] so will post this separately unless you're familiar with the issue?

Comment: @dave-everitt Sorry, I thought installing bash would be pretty painless. I don't have 10.4 so I won't be able to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the source and compile it, it should install into /usr/local by default, or you can

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

just to be sure.

Actually, compiling and installing ruby from source is an easy way to be sure you have the latest version, especially if you use git and github:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Comment: Happy to do that, but I need to preserve the system Ruby on OS X and switch to it as necessary, hence the RVM option - unless there's another way?

Comment: @Dave I don't have one in front of me, but I thought the /usr/local tree is empty on Macs?  The system ruby is /usr/bin/ruby, which is a link to /System/Library/..long,wrong path../usr/bin/ruby  so there's no danger of overwriting it.  The OS X one-click installer: http://rubyosx.rubyforge.org/  puts ruby in /usr/local as well.  Maybe that's your answer.

Comment: It is empty by default, so installing anything custom (not just Ruby) to /usr/local on OS X ensures system upgrades don't overwrite our installs generally. The one-click installer doesn't go high enough for my system, so I'd still need to install from source. But how to swap between them?